# GitLab pipeline not building

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm trying to do just a simple commit of a YAML config file on GitLab:

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - cp -r * .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - main
```

But I'm getting an error when I try to build the pipeline, it keeps failing and the error message is:

> There has been a timeout failure or the job got stuck. Check your timeout limits or try again

And I've noticed an error message on the pipeline that says:

> Job is stuck. Check runners.

I've read about this and it seems like the issue could be not having a runner?  In example tutorials and videos I've seen people publish webpages on GitLab without using runners, so I assume you don't need runners to publish a webpage?  Then again, I've read you need a runner if you are 'running your own instance of GitLab'.

I'm using what appears to be an enterprise version of GitLab - I log in with my university and the project URL looks something like this:

https://git.doit.wisc.edu/myname/my-repo

I'm not sure if I'm 'running my own instance'? Should I need a runner, or is there another reason my pipeline is failing?

### Update

I installed a runner, but still no luck.  I'm not sure if my runner is actually active.  Here's what it looks like:

[image]

It says "runner has never contacted instance" and there is no green circle to indicate it's actually active.

If I open the runner, here's what it says:

[image]

Notice it says "active".

### Update 2

I ran `gitlab-runner verify` and the runner now has a green circle next to it, so it seems active?  But my pipeline still reads pending/stuck and I'm getting the following message:

[image]

Is there still an additional step I'm missing?

Comment: have you checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60109622/gitlab-runner-fails-to-start-this-job-is-stuck-because-you-dont-have-any-activ

Comment: Hope you already added tags to the jobs, as your runner config says it will not be used for untagged jobs.